# Jacobian conversion for double integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

> Evaluate $\displaystyle \iint_R (x^2+y^2) \, dx \, dy$, where $R$ is the region in the first quadrant bounded by the curves $$xy=2, \, xy=4, \, x^2-y^2=3, \, x^2-y^2=5.$$

I have to use the Jacobian. I let $u=xy, \, v=x^2-y^2$.
So I have the region $$1 \le u \le 3, \, 1 \le v \le 5.$$

But how do I express $x^2+y^2$ in terms of $u$ and $v$? I am sure there is an algebraic manipulation. I don't want to use the quadratic formula. :(

Comment: i don't think it is possible to express the quantity in terms of $u$ and $v$.

Answer (score 2):

Use formula

$(x^2-y^2)^2=(x^2+y^2)^2-4x^2y^2$

So $x^2+y^2=\sqrt{v^2+4u^2}$